# WDSL2Java exception when I run it on https URL

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, keytool

I am trying to run wsdl2java command on https webservice, but I am getting this exception:

```
C:\axis2-1.6.2\bin>wsdl2java.bat -uri https://myserver.ad:8443/PAS/services/WSCentralService?wsdl
Using AXIS2_HOME:   C:\axis2-1.6.2
Using JAVA_HOME:    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axis2.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: Error parsing WSDL
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.<init>(CodeGenerationEngine.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:35)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1886)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:515)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1299)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.<init>(CodeGenerationEngine.java:99)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
        at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:142)
        at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:91)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:347)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:203)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
        ... 15 more
```

I ran the keytool command to import/export the certificate for myserver url, but still, i am getting this error!

Please Help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Axis 1.4, after run running the keytool again, but this time I pointed to keystore cacerts that exists on HAVA_HOME\jre\lib\security\cacerts

I saved the web service to WSCentralService.wsdl in asix 1.4 home folder\lib

and then I run the Axis command:

```
java -classpath activation.jar;mailapi.jar;axis.jar;jaxrpc.jar;saaj.jar;commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;commons-discovery-0.2.jar;wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar;log4j-1.2.8.jar org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java -s WSCentralService.wsdl
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with wsdl2java, but if you're open to another options consider trying [Apache's XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/).
Using [scomp (Schema Compiler)](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/guide/tools.html#scomp) you can generate Java classes out of your webservice WSDL url.

for example you would run this:

```
scomp -dl schema -src [generated source folder name] -out [generated jar name].jar [WSDL URL] -compiler C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\bin\javac.exe
```

the command will take the `[WSDL URL]` you've supplied, generate a folder with java source files and a .jar as well.
of course you would have to direct it to your java installation path.